# Get value of dynamically added button

Tags: jquery

I am building a simple questionnaire application.

My current function retrieves the options of each question and append them as buttons. I would like to code another function preparefornextquestion to alert the value of whichever button is selected. The current one does not seems to get the value of whichever is clicked. :(

```js
$('#option_one').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' onclick='preparefornextquestion()' value='" + arr[0].option_one + "'>" + arr[0].option_one + "</button>").trigger('create');

$('#option_two').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' onclick='preparefornextquestion()' value='" + arr[0].option_two + "'>" + arr[0].option_two + "</button>").trigger('create');

$('#option_three').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' onclick='preparefornextquestion()' value='" + arr[0].option_three + "'>" + arr[0].option_three + "</button>").trigger('create');

function preparefornextquestion(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.option').click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("value"));
        });
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="option_one"></div>     
<div id="option_two"></div> 
<div id="option_three"></div>
```

Comment: what is `arr` ?

Comment: Hi, arr is the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#option_one').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' onclick='preparefornextquestion(this)' value='" + arr[0].option_one + "'>" + arr[0].option_one + "</button>").trigger('create');

$('#option_two').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' onclick='preparefornextquestion(this)' value='" + arr[0].option_two + "'>" + arr[0].option_two + "</button>").trigger('create');

$('#option_three').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' onclick='preparefornextquestion(this)' value='" + arr[0].option_three + "'>" + arr[0].option_three + "</button>").trigger('create');


function  preparefornextquestion(val){
alert($(val).attr('value'))
}
```

Comment: That was another answer I found on stackoverflow. It was incorrect and I had removed it.

Comment: The edited solution works! Marked your answer as correct! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Fiddle try with this I don't have arr value so I just take any random value.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5apfvqb/23/)

HTML Code -

```
<div id="option_one"></div>
<div id="option_two"></div>
<div id="option_three"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT Code -

```
$('#option_one').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' value='" + 1 + "'>" + 1 + "</button>");

$('#option_two').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' value='" + 2 + "'>" + 2 + "</button>");

$('#option_three').append("<button data-role='button' class='option' data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-theme='b' value='" + 3 + "'>" + 3 + "</button>");

$('body').on('click','.option',function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```